Is this grammar LL(1)? Why so? If not, make it LL(1)
A -> Aac | Ab | Bb | a 
B -> Ac | Ad | ϵ 

Is this grammar LL(1)? Why so? If not, make it LL(1)
I need help solving this. I think it's not LL(1) because it has left recursion but I don't know how to get rid of it. I think it ends up being indirect left recursion after doing this:
A -> BbA' | aA'
A' -> acA' | bA' | ϵ
B -> AB' | ϵ
B' -> c | d


You should have been taught how to do this. Review your notes.

@user207421 can you offer me a solution to the problem?

You are correct that the left recursion makes these rules not LL(1).
First realise that  can be eliminated by just inserting the rules for it in the rules for :
       →  |  |  |  |  | 
Now we have a typical case of direct left recursion.
Wikipedia on left recursion explains a way to get rid of the left recursion.
First we get for :
       → ' | '
And for the "tail":
      ' → ' | ' | ' | ' | ϵ
Now we clearly have an LL(1) grammar as for each look-ahead terminal ,, or , we know which rule to apply.
